# How to do replace with the dte editor

Tags: console, replace, text, editors

The [dte editor](https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/#documentation) a small and easy to use console text editor.

In readme or its online doc, both says:

> - Regex [search](https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html#search) and [replace](https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html#replace)

(are the key features). However, I haven't found how to do the `replace` anywhere yet.

Even `man dte` doesn't mention anything about the `replace` operation, or how to get into the command mode to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default keybinding for command mode of `dte` is `Alt + x`<sup>[2](https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html)</sup>.

To replace<sup>[1](https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html#replace)</sup> a pattern, enter command mode (`:` prompt) and type

```
replace 'pattern to replace' 'pattern to replace with'
```

---

<sup>1.  See the examples: https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html#replace.</sup>
<sup>2. The command mode of the editor (Alt+x): https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dterc.html</sup>
<sup>3. For more `dte` default keybindings: https://craigbarnes.gitlab.io/dte/dte.html#key-bindings and https://unkertmedia.com/11-debian-terminal-text-editors-to-try/ .</sup>